# Injecting try/catch block for serializable check in bytecode through ASM

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation, jvm-bytecode

I am new to ASM and I want some help related to bytecode transformation.

I would like to add print function with try/catch block for every local variable in bytecode through ASM. I found that previous questions about adding try/catch block were about the entire method.
I know little about the stack map frame, so any pointers would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

What I expected for every object, e.g. `someObject`: print the serialized representation for it if this object is serializable, if not, use toString() to print:

```
try {
  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
  oos.writeObject(someObject);
  String serializedObject = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bos.toByteArray());
  oos.close();
  System.out.println(serializedObject);
} catch (IOException ex) {
  System.out.println(someObject.toString());
}
```

Since I'm trying to do this for every object, so I override `visitVarInsn()` in `MethodVisitor`, as following:

```
@Override
public void visitVarInsn(int opcode, int var) {
  super.visitVarInsn(opcode, var);
  switch (opcode) {
    case Opcodes.ASTORE:
      Label tryStart = new Label ();
      Label tryEnd = new Label ();
      Label catchStart = new Label ();
      Label catchEnd = new Label ();
      mv.visitTryCatchBlock(tryStart, tryEnd, catchStart, "java/io/IOException");

      mv.visitLabel(tryStart);
      // ==> ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      mv.visitTypeInsn(Opcodes.NEW, "java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream");
      mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.DUP);
      mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream", "<init>", "()V", false);
      mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ASTORE, var + 1);
      // ==> ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
      mv.visitTypeInsn(Opcodes.NEW, "java/io/ObjectOutputStream");
      mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.DUP);
      mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, var + 1);
      mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "java/io/ObjectOutputStream", "<init>", "(Ljava/io/OutputStream;)V", false);
      mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ASTORE, var + 2);
      // ==> oos.writeObject(someObject);
      mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, var + 2);
      mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, var);
      mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/ObjectOutputStream", "writeObject", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)V", false);
      // ==> String serializedObject = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bos.toByteArray());
      mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, "java/util/Base64", "getEncoder", "()Ljava/util/Base64$Encoder;", false);
      mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, var + 1);
      mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream", "toByteArray", "()[B", false);
      mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/util/Base64$Encoder", "encodeToString", "([B)Ljava/lang/String;", false);
      mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ASTORE, var + 3);
      // ==> oos.close();
      mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, var + 2);
      mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/ObjectOutputStream", "close", "()V", false);
      // ==> System.out.println
      mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
      mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, var + 3);
      mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);

      mv.visitLabel(tryEnd);
      mv.visitJumpInsn(Opcodes.GOTO, catchEnd);

      mv.visitLabel(catchStart);
      mv.visitVarInsn(ASTORE, var + 1); // store exception
      // ==> System.out.println
      mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
      mv.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, var);
      mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/Object", "toString", "()Ljava/lang/String;", false);
      mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);

      mv.visitLabel(catchEnd);

      // not sure whether I should add this.
      mv.visitLocalVariable("e", "Ljava/io/IOException;", null, catchStart, catchEnd, var + 1);
      break;
    default: // do nothing
  }
}
```

But when I tested, I keep getting `NotSerializableException` -- I thought I used try-catch to catch this exception.

I'm not sure whether I should add `visitFrame` for try-catch block (and I also don't know how to do it).

PS -- Any pointers about other better methods to do logging for every local variable would also be highly appreciated!

Comment: You are injecting too much. You are potentially overwriting variables used by the original code (unless you’re using `LocalVariableSorter`) and injecting this code block for every store operation will make the code size explode. Create a dedicated method encapsulating the operation of your first code snippet, can be compiled ordinarily, and just inject an invocation of that helper method.

Comment: Further, note that to ensure that all serialized data has been flushed to the `ByteArrayOutputStream` you have to `close` the `ObjectOutputStream` *before* calling `toByteArray()`. But why do you think the base64 encoded serialized data is better than the `toString()` output?

Comment: @Holger The reason to generate the serialized data is that I would like to deserialize those data back to object and do comparison.

Comment: @Holger Inject an invocation -- do you mean doing it outside `MethodVisitor`?

Comment: No, just create a method somewhere, say `public static void printSerializedWithToStringFallback(Object someObject)` in class `mypackage.MyUtil` containing all the code and then, instead of all the complicated code, you’re just doing `super.visitVarInsn(opcode, var); if(opcode == Opcodes.ASTORE) {  super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, var);  super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "mypackage/MyUtil", "printSerializedWithToStringFallback", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)V", false); }` to inject a call to that method passing the object to print.

Comment: Thanks so much! I made it work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic of building a try-catch block is correct, except that you are using variables `var + 1` to `var + 3` which may clash with uses by the original code. When I try your code to instrument an example specifically chosen such that it has no such variable clashes, it works.

You could work-around such issues using a [`LocalVariablesSorter`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/commons/LocalVariablesSorter.html) but it requires calls to `newLocal` to declare a variable for your injected code and since there’s no such call in your code, I assume, you’re not using `LocalVariablesSorter`.

Generally, injecting code of such complexity, even potentially multiple times, not only is error prone, it might raise the code size significantly, up to the point that it exceeds the maximum code size of a method.

The preferable approach is to move the complex code in a method on its own, which might even be delivered in precompiled form, i.e. created using ordinary Java source code, and only inject an invocation of that method.

So, assuming a helper class like

```java
package mypackage;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Base64;

public class MyUtil {
    public static void printSerializedWithToStringFallback(Object someObject) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            oos.writeObject(someObject);
            oos.close();
            System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bos.toByteArray()));
          } catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(someObject.toString());
          }
    }
}
```

You can inject the invocation like

```java
@Override
public void visitVarInsn(int opcode, int var) {
    super.visitVarInsn(opcode, var);
    if(opcode == Opcodes.ASTORE) {
        super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, var);
        super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "mypackage/MyUtil",
            "printSerializedWithToStringFallback", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)V", false);
    }
}
```

Injecting this invocation does not introduce any branches, so the stack map table does not need to be recalculated. Even the requirements for the stack do not change. The injected code does not introduce new local variables and its highest stack size, after the `aload`, is identical to the stack size before the `astore`. So this simple instrumentation does not need the [`COMPUTE_FRAMES`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html#COMPUTE_FRAMES) option and not even [`COMPUTE_MAXS`](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html#COMPUTE_MAXS).

Comment: I tried your methods to log local variables. In most cases, it works fine, but in some cases, it got `VerifyError: Bad local variable type` with the reason `Type top (current frame, locals[14]) is not assignable to reference type` for `ALOAD`. I thought every `ASTORE` could have an `ALOAD`, but sometimes it failed with `not assignable`. Any idea about this?

Comment: There is one corner case. When you have rather old bytecode (targeting Java 6 or older), you may encounter `jsr`/`ret` pairs which have a strange asymmetry. `jsr` will push a *returnaddress* to the stack, but `ret` expects the *returnaddress* in a local variable. To support this, `astore` can pop such a *returnaddress* and store it into a local variable. But `aload` can not read a *returnaddress*. Otherwise, I don’t know a case where reading immediately after storing should fail. But seeing the complete `VerifyError` would be helpful. Usually, it includes the entire bytecode for analysis.